# Palm Backup - PBB

Tags: backup, cellular

Someone else gave me a PBB file that is a backup file from a Palm Treo 700.  Anybody know how I can convert it?  What software creates this file?  I tried installing Palm Desktop 6.2.2 but it doesn't look like it support this file type.   I also tried converting it using [this online tool](http://www.sixpak.org/pbbreader/) but unfortunately it doesn't retain the e-mail addresses.  I'd prefer not to pay for a tool... as I'm doing this as a favor for a friend

Comment: Do you know it the .pbb is a text file or some kind of binary or archive?

Comment: It looks like a text file with a bunch of null terminated strings consisting of names and phone numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the user got the PBB file from verizon when they transferred her contacts from another phone.  I ended up finding the accompanying html file that came with the PBB, which I was able to extract the contacts from using excel.